# Extend Array constrained when Element is a tuple

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, swift2

Is there a way to extend an Array when the element is a type of tuple ?

```
public extension Array where Element: (timeZoneName: String, formattedName: String){

}
```

> This declaration returns 4 errors:
>
> - Statement cannot begin with a closure expression
> - Braced block statements is an unused closure
> - Expected '{' in extension
> - Expected identifier for type name

I can't tell if the errors shown are accurate.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you create a class?

Comment: Do you mean a subclass of Array ?

Comment: just a new class with those two properties

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3** version of [appzYourLife](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1761687/appzyourlife)'s answer:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element == Tuple2 {
    func foo() {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's now possible in Swift 3.1.

```
extension Array where Element == (String, String) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since (AFAIK) the `Tuple` type does not conform to a `Protocol` (and does not even have a name) it's very hard to do what you need.

This is the closest I could get (maybe others can provide more elegant solutions).

### Typealias

First of all lets define a couple of typealiases

```
typealias Tuple2 = (Any, Any)
typealias Tuple3 = (Any, Any, Any)
```

> Yes, some readers now understand where I am going and probably don't like it...
>
> I don't like it neither

### SequenceType

Now let's extend the protocol `SequenceType` adding the `foo` method when the `Element` of the sequence is `Tuple2`...

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Tuple2 {
    func foo() {}
}
```

or `Tuple3`

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element == Tuple3 {
    func foo() {}
}
```

### Array

Next lets define and populate an array of `Tuple2`

```
let list: [Tuple2] = [(1,2)]
```

Now the extension is applied and we can write

```
list.foo()
```

### Disclaimer :D

This does work only if the array is explicitly declared as `[Tuple2]` (or `[Tuple3]`).

Something like this does **not** work

```
let list = [(1,2)]
list.foo() // compile error
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't add specific typing like `extension Array where Element == Int` because this would transform the generic Array into a non-generic version.

You will see an error something like `same-type requirement makes generic parameter 'Element' non-generic`

**Edit**

<s>It does actually seem legit (at least in Swift 2.2) to do:</s>

```
typealias tzTuple = (timeZoneName: String, formattedName: String)

extension Array where Element: tzTuple  {

}
```

You will have to see if this works in runtime though.

I was checking this in a Playground and at present, Playgrounds are not yet fully functional with Swift 2.2-dev

I would suggest this instead:

```
typealias tzTuple = (timeZoneName: String, formattedName: String)

extension Array {

  func formattedName(index: Int) -> String? {
    if self[index] is tzTuple {
      return (self[index] as! tzTuple).formattedName
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

will allow you to do

```
let foo = [(timezoneName: "PST", formattedName: "Pacific Standard Time"),(timezoneName: "AEST", formattedName: "Australian Eastern Time")]
print(foo.formattedName(0))
```

Comment: That would be great, I´m currently using swift 2.1. Hope that the next Xcode comes with 2.2

Comment: it's a year later and there have been many changes in Swift. Rather than downvoting my original answer, either create a new correct answer or upvote alternates.